# Make entire div open bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, erb

I have a div with some content. I would like a click **anywhere** on the div to open to a modal. I've tried the code below. This works fine except when clicking the username link **inside** the div, the modal opens briefly before the page redirects to the correct link.  Is there a way to escape the bootstrap modal click on the links inside the div?

```
<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#post-<%= post.id %>-content">
    <div class="post-div">
        <%= link_to post.user.name, post.user %>            
        <br/><span class="title"><%= post.title %></span>
        <br/><%= post.summary %>                
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="post-<%= post.id %>-content" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="post-<%= post.id %>-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="post-<%= post.id %>-label"><%= post.title %></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <%= post.content %>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you saying you don't want the link to redirect? you want clicking anywhere on the div to open the modal. Is this correct?

Comment: @SunnyK I would like for a click anywhere in the div to open the modal except for a click on the link in the div - that should go to the link itself.  Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to pull the username link out of the modal toggle div? Something like:

```
    <%= link_to post.user.name, post.user %> 
    <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#post-<%= post.id %>-content">
       <div class="post-div">           
           <br/><span class="title"><%= post.title %></span>
           <br/><%= post.summary %>                
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: if possible I would like to keep the username inside the div, however when it is clicked I do not want the modal to pop up before the page is redirected to the user name link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jQuery loaded and the link has an ID 'the-link-above':

```html
<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#post-<%= post.id %>-content">
    <div class="post-div">
        <%= link_to post.user.name, post.user %>
        <script>
        $('#the-link-above').on('click', function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        });  
        </script>
        <br/><span class="title"><%= post.title %></span>
        <br/><%= post.summary %>                
    </div>
</div>
```

Beside, you might like this: http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/